# How to create a undeletable folder in an online mailbox in Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I have a customer hosted in Exchange online, they'd like to create some folders that are undeletable and unmovable by their users, they do want users to be able to copy items into and out of the folders, the folders cannot be shared.  I've been casting about for a MAPI property that would do the trick but PR_ACCESS is read-only/computed.  I know I can create an add-in that prevents folders from move/delete but the solution needs to work in OWA as well as Outlook.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do that - all folders in the primary mailbox are read/write. If you open a delegate store, you can set the folder ACL.